# SharePoint Address Book Lookup in Person Field

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

We have a WSS 3.0 server running in an Active Directory environment. When I'm editing a Person field in a SharePoint list I can click on the address book icon to pop-up a window where I can search for active directory users to add.

This list of users in this pop-up window is empty until I enter a search term and click the magnifying glass icon to search for users. I thought that this pop-up window would be initially populated with all of the users in the Active Directory.

Is there a way to make this pop-up appear so that it's already populated with our full list of Active Directory users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that out of the box - you can't do it (since Active Directory might contain thousands of users and it would then be unsafe to load all of them into the popup).

A possible workaround - you can create a SharePoint group which contains all your domain users. Then - limit the person picker to show only members of that group. Then it would display the list of all group members.